# request a javascript variable into razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a problem, the request function its not working

Here is my code
Razor

```
@{
            int i = 0;
            List<Abono> ab = Model.ToList();
            int inicio = Convert.ToInt32(Request["inic"]);
            int fin = Convert.ToInt32(Request["ffin"]);
            var xx = ab.Skip(inicio).Take(fin);
          }
```

script

```
var inic=0;
var ffin=20;


function siguiente() {
    //debugger;
    var ini = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.inicio));
    var fi=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.fin));
    $.post("/Reportes/GetSiguiente", { Fin: fi },
            function (data) {
                var dato = data.dias;
                //alert(dato);
                debugger;
                var inic=dato[0];
                var ffin=dato[1];

            });

}
```

I am traying to change the razors values.

Thanks

Comment: You are setting local variables then referencing them from ViewBag. These are not the same thing

Comment: I need the first values, forget the ViewBags, forget the siguiente function, when the page open the first time I need to assignt the values to my razor variables. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove @ViewBag from the front of your variables.